# Display number of events in TableCalendar Flutter

Tags: flutter, table-calendar

[TableCalendar package](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) have an gif example of calendar with number of events for given day in bottom right corner of a day.

I've been going through their [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/table_calendar/latest/table_calendar/table_calendar-library.html), but haven't been able to find the solution.

I've learned that those dots are called markers, and found [MarkerBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/table_calendar/latest/table_calendar/MarkerBuilder.html), but I don't know how to implement it in my code.

[image: This is the gif with number of events in corner of each day.]

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can overwrite the markerbuilder function with your own. Something like:

```
TableCalendar(
   ...
   calendarStyle: const CalendarStyle(
      markersAlignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
   ),
   calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
      markerBuilder: (context, day, events) => events.isNotEmpty
                ? Container(
                    width: 24,
                    height: 24,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      '${events.length}',
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  )
                : null,
   )

)
```

You can put pretty much anything you like there, as its just another widget.